# Displaying friends' user who authenticated the app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm going more in depth in the Facebook javascript sdk but I am still new to it. I would like to display for every user on my website who logged with Facebook, their friends' pictures who also authorized the app. It is clearly and simply possible by using PHP SDK, but I only want to make use of javascript SDK to improve the speed of my site. Does anyone have an idea ?

Best,

Newben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use FQL to query the current user's friends  `SELECT id, name FROM user where uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friends WHERE uid2=me()) AND is_app_user=1`. This query does two things.  Finds all the friends and find only the friends who have your app installed.

For additional information see:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

and

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/